# Which of an OAuth 2.0 provider's JWKs should be used to verify an OpenID Connect `id_token`?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, jwk

If an authentication server supplies multiple JSON Web Keys (e.g. https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs) which should be used to verify an OpenID Connect `id_token` as part of the OPenID Connect Implicit Flow?

Should the `id_token` be verified with the first JSON Web Key, all of the JSON Web Keys, or is the `id_token` considered valid if it can be verified with any of these provided JSON Web Keys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are multiple keys in play that the OpenID Connect provider could use to sign an `id_token`, the header of the `id_token` would typically contain a key identifier (in the `kid` element) of the key that is actually used. That corresponds to the `kid` element in the JWK published on the (jwks_uri) endpoint that you describe. So the `id_token` would only be valid if it can be verified using the key that is associated with the `kid` in the header.